# Setup Lamp on Hetzner server

Tags: linux, server, debian, lamp, yum

I am using debian 8.0 Hetzner server and trying to setup Lamp on it, I am following this tutorial to setup Lamp.
[Installing a LAMP Web Server on Amazon Linux](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html)

So I began with

> yum update -y

and it showed me error **yum: command not found**

so I ran this command

> apt-get install yum

and it worked

On using this command

> yum update -y

it shows

**There are no enabled repos.
 Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos you have.
 You can enable repos with yum-config-manager --enable**

Whats the solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you even want to install yum if you have apt-get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using debian, yum is for centos/redhat distribution.
You need to use aptitude to install packages ( apt-get install command).

Take a look at this, it could be usefull :

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-debian